# how can I plot a linear regression with error bars in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-regression

I was studying the linear-regression of this data set with the error bars but when I run the program it doesn't show the error bars

```
tempint = [0.18569,0.530445,0.83078,1.09996,1.34653,1.576,1.7911];
vist = [0.269266,0.314337,0.353932,0.3909,0.421372,0.451202, 0.479455];
a = polyfit(tempint,vist, 1);
y = 0.245218 + 0.130961*tempint;
err = [0.0008,0.0008,0.0008,0.0008,0.0008,0.0008,0.0008];
errorbar(vist,err);
plot(tempint,y);
xlabel("tempo intermedio [s]")
ylabel("velocità istantanea [m/s]")
```

can someone explain to me what it's wrong with that? thank you in advance

Comment: Do a `hold on` after `errorbar`. Otherwise `plot` will delete the figure before plotting.

Comment: If you run your program one line at the time, you can see what it's doing. I highly recommend that as an introduction to debugging. And it's so easy to do in MATLAB!